# Windows Server system time drifts badly on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2, ntp

We've been using an EC2 micro instance for a little remote monitoring for the past few weeks, and it's bothered me badly how the system time is never accurate; no matter how much fighting I did with Windows time syncing, it was never working properly.  Didn't find an answer on serverfault that explained how to fix it, but found a good one finally on Amazon's forums, and wanted to share it here for anyone else looking.

Scenario:  Windows 2003 Server on EC2 Micro

Situation:  Time always wants to sync to UTC, no matter what is configured in Windows.

Answer (score -1):

> I figured I'd add an update about our experience with this - we have
>   found that using a third-party app to update the time makes the
>   problem worse. The app works great but we find that the time changes
>   every hour and then the app has to correct it. If we configure Windows
>   time sync to use NTP then the time stays correct and the third-party
>   software is not necessary.
>
> Here is what we do to configure Windows time sync:
>
> First ensure that you can get time from a NTP server, otherwise the
>   instructions below are not going to work. To test, get the current
>   variance from an NTP server using the following Windows Time service
>   command w32tm /stripchart /samples:5 /computer:pool.ntp.org /dataonly
>
> In a VPC we had to open UDP port 123 for inbound connections in the
>   NAT security group.
>
> To configure NTP time sync in Windows
>
> 1. Registry edit - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
>      Set SpecialPollInterval to polling interval in seconds (we set ours to
>      60).
> 2. Registry edit - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters
>      Set Type to NTP
> 3. Run the following commands to configure the time servers (can use other servers, we're using 4 time servers - 0.pool.ntp.org,
>      time.nist.gov, 1.pool.ntp.org, and 2.pool.ntp.org) net stop w32time
>      w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual
>      /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org,0x1 time.nist.gov,0x1
>      1.pool.ntp.org,0x1 2.pool.ntp.org,0x1" net start w32time
>
> To review the config w32tm /query /configuration
>
> To check the sync against a time server w32tm /stripchart /samples:5
>   /computer:pool.ntp.org /dataonly

Source: [Time on my EC2 windows instance changed automatically](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=428855)